# Difference between head and tail

Tags: command-line, tail

Why is there a difference between the meaning of NUM in `head -c` and `tail -c`?

I will clarify what I mean with the following commands:

```
$ echo "words" | tail -c +1
words
$ echo "words" | tail -c +2
ords
$ echo "words" | head -c -1
words$ echo "words" | head -c -2
word$
```

The first command does nothing.
The second command removes the first letter.
The third command removes the newline.
The last command removes the last 2 characters including the newline.

So why does head removes 2 bytes when using `-c` and tail only one. This looks like some real inconsistency or is there an underlying meaning?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Citing `man tail`:

> use -c +NUM to output starting with byte NUM of each file

Citing `man head`:

> -c (…) [-]NUM
>   with the leading '-', print all but the last NUM bytes of each file(…)

The logic with

```
tail -c +1
```

is to print all **from** byte number `1`, i.e. the first byte, while with

```
head -c -1
```

it’s to print all **but** the last `1` byte.